# Change volume inside app without playing music

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-audio, system-sounds

My problem is:

1) I'm in an iOS application
2) I change volume (clicking volume buttons) while no sounds from app is being played -> system sound volume is changed.

Is there any way to change volume of app sounds without playing them?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to change the volume of iPhone from your app without showing it to user?

Comment: I want to change volume of sounds in my app while being in app. But when I'm in an app and any sounds are not played, system sounds volume is changed not app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1;
```

[MPMusicPlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

This way you set device volume.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [[MPMusicPlayerController alloc] init];
player.volume = 0.25;
[player release];
```